# Php RandomPick Numbers

Tags: php, mysql

1. I have an HTML from with 9 checkboxes, ie, Checkbox 1 value=1-10, checkbox 2 value = 11-20......to checkbox 10 with value=80-90.
2. A mysql table called 'frequency' with 2 fields: number and frequency. Number holds numbers from 1 to 90.

QUESTION:

I would like to be able to SELECT numbers based on their frequency, that is, If I click on checkbox 1-10 and checkbox 30-40, I should get all the numbers from the table that are in the RANGE 1-10 and RANGE 30-40 based on their frequency.

Thanks in advance to all responders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`If I click on check box 1-10`**

```
$checkbox = $_REQUEST['first_checkbox'];
// it will return value 1-10 which is being posted.
$val = explode("-", $a);
```

**Your query should be :**

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
    -> WHERE range BETWEEN $val[0] AND $val[1];
```

Similarly for the rest.

Comment: thanks a lot hey, what i am trying to archive is here: http://www.luckynumbers.co.zw/generator.aspx